# Unity 3D and authenticating using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory (OAuth2.0)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I'm recently working in a little application using Unity 3D and C#, and I'd like to consume a service to retrieve data to present, this service is using OAuth2.0, which I always consume in an standard C# application by using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory package, but it seems like I cannot use it in a C# Unity app. I tried installing the Nuget package in the Unity built application but it threw incompability issues and I don't see any option to install Nuget packages when you open the scripts from within Unity.

I do have some experience in C# but I'm just starting with Unity so I would appreciate any guidance, thanks a lot!

Comment: I dont know which version of Oauth I use, but I get to use a web login and receive a token which i then send to followup web sites